# How to set minDate and maxDate for bootstrap datetimepicker on change

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I want to ask users for a date range using bootstrap datetimepicker. There is a field for the start date and another one for the end date, and they're initialized to the day before current day. On change to the start date, I want to set the minDate of end date to the value of start date; and on change to end date I want to set the max date of start date to the value of end date. But I cannot get this working.

Here is the JS code:

```
var start = $('.start');
var end = $('.end');
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate() - 1;
var year = d.getFullYear();

start.datetimepicker(
    {
        useCurrent: false,
        defaultDate: month + '-' + day + '-' + year + ' ' + '12:00AM',
        autoClose: true
     })
 .on('change', function (selected) {
    end.minDate(selected.?????????); // What should replace the question marks?
 });
end.datetimepicker(
    {
        useCurrent: false,
        defaultDate: month + '-' + day + '-' + year + ' ' + '11:59PM',
        autoClose: true
     })
 .on('change', function (selected) {
    start.maxDate(selected.???????); // What should replace the question marks?
 });
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h4>Start Date</h4>
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" data-data-fomat="MM-DD-YYY h:mm A" data-ng-model="startDate" id="Calendar1" class="start form-control" placeholder="Choose a date" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h4>End Date</h4>
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" data-data-fomat="MM-DD-YYY h:mm A" data-ng-model="endDate" id="Calendar2" class="end form-control" placeholder="choose a date" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've found tickets about similar operation on `datepicker`, but that is done differently from `datetimepicker` so please don't mark duplicate unless you find similar question for `datetimepicker`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on the [Linked Pickers example](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers) in the [Bootstrap datetimepicker documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), this should work.

Start:

```
 .on('dp.change', function (selected) {
    end.data("DateTimePicker").minDate(selected.date);
 });
```

End:

```
 .on('dp.change', function (selected) {
    start.data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(selected.date);
 });
```

Note:

On older versions of Bootstrap datetimepicker (less than v4), use `.setMinDate` and `.setMaxDate`

Comment: not working for me this is the error `$(...).data(...).setMinDate is not a function`

Comment: @GauravAggarwal can you check the updated answer? (Use `.minDate` instead of `.setMinDate`)

The linked example seems to have been updated around the time the library moved to v4
The [changelog](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Changelog/) doesn't mention it though

Comment: How to do it for dynamically added elements??

Answer (score 2):

1. Start Date

   ```
   .on('dp.change', function (selected) {
       end.data("DateTimePicker").minDate(selected.date);
    });
   ```
2. End Date

   ```
   .on('dp.change', function (selected) {
       start.data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(selected.date);
    });
   ```

**Package Upgrade** :
                                                               The date timepicker package has been upgraded to latest version where we can use 'maxDate()' in place of 'setMaxDate()' and 'minDate()' inplace of 'setMinDate()' as the recent options consider even time in hrs and mins while providing maxDate/minDate option.

Comment: How to do it for dynamically added elements??

Comment: I believe at the time of creation of elements which can be something like `click` event

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$('.datepickerProjectDate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate('2018-09-15');
```