# Meteor setTimeout until current date

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor

I want to configure my form with a birth date

This sis my html code

```
<div class="birthdate input-field col s6">
    <label for="birthdate" class="active">Birth date</label>
    <input id="birthdate" name="birthdate" type="date" class="datepicker"/>
</div>
```

and this is my javascript code

```
Meteor.setTimeout( function() {
    var input = template.$('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 100, // Creates a dropdown of 100 years to control year
        format: "dd/mmm/yyyy",

    });
```

and I just want to show in my calendar until the current date.

Comment: What's the `setTimeout` for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use maxDate option which is available in datepicker, here is link to similar question

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977783/how-to-set-mindate-and-maxdate-for-bootstrap-datetimepicker-on-change/33992544#33992544)
. For docs [docs](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

I did it !!

only adding

```
max: true
```

in this part:

```
Meteor.setTimeout( function() {
    var input = template.$('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 100, // Creates a dropdown of 100 years to control year
        format: "dd/mmm/yyyy",
        max: true

    });
```