# Linked DateTimepickers should not allow certain dates

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I am using a boostrap-datetimepicker plugin and on my page i have 2 Linked Pickers(named **startPicker** and **endPicker**) i have configured both the pickers through their options not allow the future date but i a have a startPicker that should only allow selection the past dates not including today and i have an endPicker that should only allow selection of past dates including today starting from the date of selected startPicker. With configuration for the endPicker the user is able to select the date lower than the selected date in startPicker. Is there a way to get the selected date in startPicker ?

```js
 $(function (){
            
            const yesterdayDate = new Date();
            yesterdayDate.setDate(yesterdayDate.getDate() - 1); //Yesterday date

            $('#startPicker').datetimepicker({
                maxDate: yesterdayDate,
            });

            
            $('#endPicker').datetimepicker({
                minDate: yesterdayDate,
                maxDate: new Date()
            });

 });
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573624/get-the-value-of-bootstrap-datetimepicker-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977783/how-to-set-mindate-and-maxdate-for-bootstrap-datetimepicker-on-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('#endPicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: yesterdayDate,
    maxDate: new Date()
});

$('#Startpicker').on('dp.change', (selected) => { 
    $('#endPicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(selected.date);
})
```

This code watches for changes to startPicker then updates endPicker's minDate.

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much mate! This made it works as i wanted to. Appreciate